# Set of all finite subsets of the natural numbers is not able to create an infinite sequence?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I am currently starting to study topology through the Topology without Tears book, and I came across the Example 1.1.5 and I am not sure if I understand why is the result like it is. The example says as it follows:

> Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all natural numbers and let $\tau_4$ consist of $\mathbb{N}, \emptyset$, and all finite substes of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $\tau_4$ is not a topology on $\mathbb{N}$ because the infinite union $\{2\} \cup \{3\} \cup ... \cup \{n\} \cup ... = \{2,3,...,n, ...\}$ is not in $\tau_4$.

I guess that the result comes from the fact that only finite subsets are considered, but I don't see why an infinite union of finite set wouldn't generate an infinite set.

To put an example of my thinking about this example. Since all the finite subsets in $\mathbb{N}$ is in $\tau_4$ and any combination $\{k, k+1\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, given that $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and any combination of them is also a a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, why is it not in $\tau_4$?

P.S. I think I start to get it, is it because we are explicitly indicating that only the finite sets are part of $\tau_4$?

Comment: I think "and all of $\Bbb N$" was meant to read "and all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$". The whole point of this example is that an infinite union of finite sets can be infinite, and a topology must be closed under infinite unions, so this shows that $\tau_4$ is not a topology. Can you say a bit more about what you don't understand?

Comment: Maybe you wonder whether EVERY union of infinite pairwise distinct subsets of $\mathbb N$ is infinite. The answer is yes , if it were finite, there were only a finite number of subsets , namely $2^m$ , if $m$ is the number of elements.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen According to the definition I have of a topology, the union of any (finite or infinite) number of sets in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$. I don't see how the infinite union of finite sets is not in it.

Comment: Is it the statement
$$
\{2, 3, 4, \ldots\}\notin \tau_4
$$
that you don't understand? Or is it 
$$
\{2\}\cup\{3\}\cup\cdots = \{2, 3, \ldots\}
$$or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, it's true that if $\tau$ is a family of sets that is a topology, then the union of an infinite number of sets in $\tau$ must belong to $\tau$. What is happening in this example is that the author takes $\tau$ to be a particular family of sets, and shows that it is not a topology because it fails to have this property. This example is interesting/useful because it shows that "closed under finite unions" does not imply "closed under infinite unions".

Comment: An analagous situation might be: "say a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is a *linear subspace* if it contains $0$, it's closed under addition and closed under multiplication by scalars. Consider $S = \Bbb Z^2 \subseteq \Bbb R^2$. Then $S$ contains $0$, and is closed under addition but not closed under multiplication by scalars, so $S$ is not a linear subspace". If you still don't understand, can you try to point to exactly which sentence in the book doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: @Arthur the first one

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think I start to get it, is it because we are explicitly indicating that only the finite sets are part of τ4?

Comment: Yes, that's right - $\tau_4$ is defined to be the set whose elements are $\Bbb N$ and every finite subset of $\Bbb N$, and no more than that. This is how you should always read "let $S$ consist of ..." - it means those are *exactly* the elements of $S$, not just that they're *some* of the elements.